# having trouble acquiring Int from "gets(*buffer)"

Tags: c, struct

So my tutor asked me to acquire an integer for a data struct , but 2 of the int parts im supposed to get , is via gets , im thinking he meant me to use gets(temp) // temp stand for char temp[50] and then perform x=strlen(temp);
here is my work so far :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N 20

struct one
{
    int ak;
    char pin[N];    
};

struct two
{
    int data,mat[N];
    struct one melos,item;
};

int main(void)
{
    bool x=true;
    int i;
    char temp[N];
    struct one person;
    struct two memb;

    /*GETTING VARS*/
    gets(person.pin);
    gets(memb.item.pin);
    gets(memb.melos.pin);
    person.ak=(int)gets(temp); 
    memb.data=(int)gets(temp);  
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%d",&memb.mat[i]);
    scanf("%d",&memb.melos.ak);
    scanf("%d",&memb.item.ak);

    putchar('\n');

    /*CHECKING VARS*/
    puts("Posting vars in Data Struct ""one"" \n");
    printf("%d\n",person.ak);
    puts(person.pin);
    puts("Posting vars in Data Struct ""two"" \n");
    printf("%d\n",memb.data);
    putchar('\n');
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%d\t",memb.mat[i]);
    printf("\n%d\n",memb.melos.ak);
    puts(memb.melos.pin);
    printf("%d\n",memb.item.ak);
    puts(memb.item.pin);
    puts("**********************\n---POST_END---");

    return 1;                   
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: Also , when i try to compile the above code , im getting an error : 32 26 C:\Users\ÐÝôñïò-Êùóôáíôßíïò\Documents\Data Structures\LAB 3\xDEV.cpp [Error] cast from 'char*' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive]

Comment: `person.ak=(int)gets(temp); `...erm..no, not at all.

Comment: gets was marked as obsolete 17 years ago and completely removed from the C language 5 years ago. And then there's conio.h which has been obsolete for at least 20 years. You need to learn C from a different source, the one you are currently learning from is hopelessly outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `gets()` is the pointer to the buffer passed if successful, and `NULL` if failed. It won't mean the integer read.

Also note that you shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

You will have to convert the string read to integer.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> /* for using atoi() */
#include<string.h>

#define N 20

/* read one line while checking the size read */
char* safer_gets(char* outbuf, size_t max){
    size_t idx = 0;
    int input;
    if(max == 0) return NULL;
    while(idx + 1 < max && (input = getchar()) != EOF && input != '\n'){
        outbuf[idx++] = input;
    }
    if (idx == 0 && input == EOF) return NULL;
    outbuf[idx] = '\0';
    return outbuf;
}

/* read one line and convert it to integer */
int get_int(void) {
    char temp[N];
    safer_gets(temp, sizeof(temp));
    return atoi(temp);
}

struct one
{
    int ak;
    char pin[N];
};

struct two
{
    int data,mat[N];
    struct one melos,item;
};

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct one person;
    struct two memb;

    /*GETTING VARS*/
    safer_gets(person.pin, sizeof(person.pin));
    safer_gets(memb.item.pin, sizeof(memb.item.pin));
    safer_gets(memb.melos.pin, sizeof(memb.melos.pin));
    person.ak=get_int();
    memb.data=get_int();

    /* latter part omitted */
}
```

Comment: Or `fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);`

Comment: @fandyushin `fgets()` will store the newline character if it is read, while `gets()` won't. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `gets` - I'm surprised your class mentions it because it's been removed from all of the recent C language specifications and now deprecated in C++11.

But if you must...

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/

```
long int getIntegerWithGetS() {

    char* end;
    char* buffer = calloc( 1024, sizeof(char) ); // 1024 bytes should be enough

    long int result;
    bool got_result_yet = false;
    while( !got_result_yet ) {
        gets( buffer ); // DANGER WILL ROBINSON
        result = strtol( buffer, &end, 10 );
        if( result == 0 ) {
            if( end != buffer ) {
                result = 0;
                got_result_yet = true;
            }
        } else {
            if( result != LONG_MAX && result != LONG_MIN && errno != ERANGE ) got_result_yet = true;
        }
    }

    free(buffer);

    return result;
}
```

Note how I call my code in a loop so we will persist until we get valid input from the user. I start off calling `gets` (to fill the buffer), then using `strtol` to convert the human-readable text in `buffer` to an actual computer `int` value - note that `strtol` is more powerful than `atoi` and uses `long int` instead of `int` as its declared type. Then the code checks for the `strtol` error conditions (in case a user types in `"0"` when the function returns `0` on failure anyway).

I don't return immediately, because the `buffer` must be `free`'d before execution leaves the scope, otherwise that buffer will remain unallocated and so leaked.

Comment: Why not simple `char buffer[1024] = {'\0'};` if you use fixed buffer size?

Comment: "I don't return immediately" No, you did and caused memory leak.

Comment: @MikeCAT if `buffer` was on the stack then a malicious user could cause `gets` to overspill then the user would be overwriting the stack (which usually grows-downards, remember) which would allow for the program to be hijacked, not merely crash. Using a buffer from the heap is less likely to be a security risk, though the risk of a buffer overflow is ever-present.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks - I'm not thinking straight, I've fixed it.

Comment: A semicolon is missing after the first `got_result_yet = true`.